# Arguing a function must be differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, functions, derivatives

Let $[a,b]\subset \mathbb R$ and $w \in C[a,b]$. Prove the following: if $\int_{a}^{b}w(x)h'(x)dx=0$ $\forall h\in C^1[a,b]$ with $h(a)=h(b)=0$ then $w(x)=c\in \mathbb R$ $\forall x \in [a,b].$

My attempt uses integration by parts. $\int_{a}^{b}w(x)h'(x)dx=w(b)h(b)-w(a)h(a)-\int_{a}^{b}w'(x)h(x)dx=0.$ Since $h(a)=h(b)=0$ we get $\int_{a}^{b}w'(x)h(x)dx=0.$ Since this holds $\forall h\in C^1[a,b]$ we must have $w'(x)\equiv 0$ so $w(x)\equiv c \in \mathbb R.$ One thing that needs justifying is when using integration by parts to transfer the derivative from $h(x)$ to $w(x)$ we assumed $w(x)$ is differentiable, but this is not a priori known since we are given $w(x)$ is only a $C[a,b]$ function, so not necessarily differentiable. Therefore I need to argue that $w(x)$ is in fact a $C^1[a,b]$ function but I am unsure why this must be the case.

Answer (score 1):

I have a slight problem with the previous answer because it seems to indicate that we must have $w \equiv 0$ which is not necessarily true. Here is how I would approach the problem:

First note that any $h \in C^1[a,b]$ with $h(a) = h(b) = 0$ satisfies $$\int^b_a h'(x) dx = 0.$$ And thus, if $w \in C[a,b]$ satisfies the given condition, it also satisfies \begin{equation} \tag{1}\int^b_a (w(x)-c)h'(x) dx = 0  \end{equation} where $h$ is as specified above, and $c$ is any constant. In particular, take $$c = w_{\text{avg}} = \frac{1}{b-a} \int^b_a w(t)dt,$$ and define $$h(x) = \int^x_a (w(y) - w_{\text{avg}}) dy.$$ Then $h \in C^1[a,b]$ since $w \in C[a,b]$. Also $h(a) = h(b) = 0$, and $h'(x) = w(x)-w_{\text{avg}}$. Plugging this choice of $h$ and $c$ into $(1)$ gives $$\int^b_a (w(x)-w_{\text{avg}})^2 dx = 0$$ which is possible iff $w(x) \equiv w_{\text{avg}}$, so we conclude $w$ is constant.

Comment: yeah on second inspection of kavi's answer, I noticed that too. thanks for your answer!